# How can I mark something as ‘yes’ or ‘no’ based on when two cells match as well as whether another cell is blank — in Numbers

Tags: ios, apple-numbers-formula

I’m using Numbers on an iPad (I don’t have a Mac).

I have a list of physical tools on one tab. On another tab I have a table of dates and times when the tools were checked out and checked in.

On the first tab (where the tools are listed), I’d like to have a column that says whether or not the tool is available based on whether or not it’s been checked out but not checked back in.

So I want to write a formula that looks for the name of the tool on the second tab, and when it finds it, checks to see whether any of the checkin cells are blank. If there’s a blank one, the formula should print ‘no’. If there aren’t any blank cells, the formula should print ‘yes’.

Is this possible? If so, can anyone suggest a formula please? It’s a bit too complex for me… (I have rudimentary coding skills.)

Comment: The table on the first tab is called ‘Tools’
The names of the tools in that table are in column B. I’d like to put the available yes/no status in column E.

The table on the other tab is called ‘Tool checkin’.
The tool name is in column B.
The checkin cells are in column C.
A new row is added at the bottom of the column every time a tool is checked out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Xlookup may help.

With XLOOKUP, you can find values in columns and rows, or look for exact, approximate or partial matches.https://www.apple.com/au/numbers/features/

```
XLOOKUP(lookup_value, lookup_array, return_array, [if_not_found], [match_mode], [search_mode])
```

For example:

```
XLOOKUP(<cell>,Tool checkin::A,Checkin,"no",0,-1)
```

Then an if statement can turn it into a yes/no value:

```
IF(<cell>=0,"no","yes")
```